# How do I add columns to an existing excel worksheet using golang and excelize?

Tags: go, excelize

I have some go code that opens a spreadsheet and for each row, uses a lanid in the row to lookup some data. I would like to add this derived data as two new columns in the sheet.

Opening the sheet and looping over all the rows works fine. I just can't figure out how to add the new columns. Any suggestions welcome.

The code below throws an error of

panic: runtime error: index out of range [7] with length 7

like the columns haven't been added.

```
f, e := excelize.OpenFile("apps.xlsx")
if e != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

defer func() {
    if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}()

f.InsertCol("apps", "H")
f.InsertCol("apps", "H")

rows, err := f.GetRows("apps")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
for _, row := range rows {
    lanid := row[3]
    
    fmt.Print(lanid, "\t")
    fmt.Println()
    node := orgtee.lookup(lanid)
    row[7] = node.title
    row[8] = node.domain
}
```

Comment: have you try this? https://xuri.me/excelize/en/sheet.html#InsertCol

Comment: I haven't. I will give it a go before calling GetRows. Would I then just be able to use the row[7] style assignment?

Comment: I''ve tried calling InsertCol, doing a save after it, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it by `SetCellValue` function.

This is the example.

```golang
    for i := 1; i < len(rows); i++ {
        f.SetCellValue("apps", "G"+strconv.Itoa(i), "coba1")
        f.SetCellValue("apps", "H"+strconv.Itoa(i), "coba2")
        f.SetCellValue("apps", "I"+strconv.Itoa(i), "coba3")
    }

    rows, err = f.GetRows("apps") // call GetRows again to update rows value
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(rows)
```

Comment: I pit the set values inside the getrows loop and made it work. I'd like to find a way to not have hardcode the column label but thats later down the road. Thank you for your help!